# How to add custom widget to QListView?

Tags: c++, qt

I have added a QListWidget in the main window of my program. I then created a class that inherits from QWidget. Using a separate dialog box, I created new objects and added them to QListWidget. Everything was fine until I realised that when I tried to change the order of the elements in QListWidget, the contents of the individual elements were being deleted. I did some research on the internet and found that in order to create a list of widgets that I would want to edit (reorder) to some extent, it was best to use QListView + Model/View + Delegate.

I checked out this example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html

Unfortunately I didn't understand too much from it. I created my own (working) model and delegate,but I still don't know how to draw my widget. Below the model and delegate:

model.h

```
#ifndef OPERATIONWIDGETMODEL_H
#define OPERATIONWIDGETMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractItemModel>

class OperationWidgetModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit OperationWidgetModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    void AddItem(OperationWidget* item);

private:
    QList<OperationWidget*> widgetList;

};

#endif // OPERATIONWIDGETMODEL_H
```

model.cpp

```
#include "operationwidgetmodel.h"

OperationWidgetModel::OperationWidgetModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    //
}

QVariant OperationWidgetModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    return QVariant();
}


QModelIndex OperationWidgetModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    QModelIndex index;

    index = createIndex(row,column,nullptr);
    return index;
}

QModelIndex OperationWidgetModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return QModelIndex();
}

int OperationWidgetModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if(parent.isValid())return 0;

    return 1;
}

int OperationWidgetModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if(parent.isValid()) return 0;
    return 1;
}
void OperationWidgetModel::AddItem(OperationWidget *item)
{

    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),widgetList.count(),widgetList.count());
    widgetList.append(item);
    endInsertRows();
}
```

delegate.h

```
#ifndef OPERATIONWIDGETDELEGATE_H
#define OPERATIONWIDGETDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include "operationwidget.h"

class OperationWidgetDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    OperationWidgetDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
               const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const override;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                      const QModelIndex &index) const override;


};

#endif // OPERATIONWIDGETDELEGATE_H
```

delegate.cpp

```
#include "operationwidgetdelegate.h"



OperationWidgetDelegate::OperationWidgetDelegate(QObject *parent)
{

}

void OperationWidgetDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,option,index);
}

QSize OperationWidgetDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    OperationWidget widget;

    return QSize(widget.geometry().width(),widget.geometry().height());
}

QWidget *OperationWidgetDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    OperationWidget *widget = new OperationWidget(parent);

    return widget;
}

void OperationWidgetDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    OperationWidget *widget = qobject_cast<OperationWidget*>(editor);
    if(widget)
    {
        widget->SetOperationName("Cięcie");
    }

}

void OperationWidgetDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    OperationWidget *widget = qobject_cast<OperationWidget*>(editor);

    if(widget)
    {
        model->setData(index,widget->GetOperationName(),Qt::EditRole);
    }
}
```

Below is my widget that I want to add to the QListView:

[image]

And my QListView after I added my custom widget:

[image]

Any ideas how can I Draw my widget to QListView?
Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this line of code:

```
ui->listView->setItemDelegate(new OperationWidgetDelegate(this);
```